# No boot after installation Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, bios, pxe

After installation of Ubuntu 22.04 no success to start up linux from hard disk. I get the notification PXE-E53: no boot filename received. PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM. Non-system disk or disk error
replace and strike any key when ready.

via the boot-repair program I made the file below: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JNRQHyhxPv/

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 2048 
    of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks for (,gpt3)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_gpt biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sdb and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdb: /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on sda3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller from Intel Corporation Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 68PZI Ver. F.0F(15.15) from Hewlett-Packard
This live-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).


a9c517741ac31962d7feb152948ad1ee   sda2/BOOT/fbx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   sda2/BOOT/mmx64.efi
5ddf997e8b025bfbc2009e85b32f60dc   sda2/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   sda2/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda2/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda2/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   hasBIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda3    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda3    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda3    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 232.89 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk identifier: 7B9F4629-7ACD-4D71-B651-919915792233
        Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1     2048      4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
sda2     4096   1054719   1050624   513M EFI System
sda3  1054720 488396799 487342080 232.4G Linux filesystem
Disk sdb: 29.3 GiB, 31457280000 bytes, 61440000 sectors
Disk identifier: A0891D7E-B930-4513-94D9-F629DBD637B2
        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sdb1       64  9613459  9613396  4.6G Microsoft basic data
sdb2  9613460  9623527    10068  4.9M EFI System
sdb3  9623528  9624127      600  300K Microsoft basic data
sdb4  9625600 61439936 51814337 24.7G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:250GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA WDC WD2500BEKT-6:;
1:1049kB:2097kB:1049kB:::bios_grub;
2:2097kB:540MB:538MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
3:540MB:250GB:250GB:ext4::;
sdb:31.5GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:Intenso Slim Line:;
1:32.8kB:4922MB:4922MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:4922MB:4927MB:5155kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:4927MB:4928MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:4928MB:31.5GB:26.5GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                
├─sda1                                               c865f34f-6463-474b-acb6-2acb015584cf                          
├─sda2 vfat     824B-6AD9                            d3d53edb-52c0-4b55-8a95-603b00f7dd05                          EFI System Partition
└─sda3 ext4     3e79f0f9-fece-409d-9c7e-73b919574567 c8df39b7-8010-4f23-8b34-b30deb5ab5d7                          
sdb    iso9660  2023-02-23-04-13-44-00                                                    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS amd64 
├─sdb1 iso9660  2023-02-23-04-13-44-00               a0891d7e-b930-4513-94d8-f629dbd637b2 Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sdb2 vfat     F7DB-4D56                            a0891d7e-b930-4513-94db-f629dbd637b2 ESP                      Appended2
├─sdb3                                               a0891d7e-b930-4513-94da-f629dbd637b2                          Gap1
└─sdb4 ext4     d5e218c3-5ebb-4020-86e2-6fb04463d11c 0408afcc-157f-1d43-a356-7667305ce85d writable                 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                               Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2023-05-11.3/crash]  22.9G   0% /var/crash
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2023-05-11.3/log]    22.9G   0% /var/log
/dev/sda2                                                     505.9M   1% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda3                                                     202.6G   6% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sdb1                                                          0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


===================== sda2/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid 3e79f0f9-fece-409d-9c7e-73b919574567 root hd0,gpt3 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda3/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   3e79f0f9-fece-409d-9c7e-73b919574567
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-41-generic   3e79f0f9-fece-409d-9c7e-73b919574567
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-32-generic   3e79f0f9-fece-409d-9c7e-73b919574567
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda3/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=3e79f0f9-fece-409d-9c7e-73b919574567 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=824B-6AD9  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda3/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda3: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 168.986537933 = 181.447913472  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 167.199607849 = 179.529211904  boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
 168.162723541 = 180.563349504  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
  10.237300873 = 10.992218112   boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-32-generic                 2
 168.162723541 = 180.563349504  boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-41-generic                 1
  10.237300873 = 10.992218112   boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 169.561374664 = 182.065139712  boot/initrd.img                                1
 169.264377594 = 181.746241536  boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-32-generic              1
 169.561374664 = 182.065139712  boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-41-generic              1
 169.264377594 = 181.746241536  boot/initrd.img.old                            1

===================== sda3: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Dec  2 15:18 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Dec  2 15:18 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14180 Dec  2 15:18 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Dec  2 15:18 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Dec  2 15:18 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Sep 20  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec  2 15:18 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Dec  2 15:18 41_custom



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
sda3,
using the following options:  sda2/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Blockers in case of suggested repair: __________________________________________

 The current session is in BIOS-compatibility mode. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB) that is compatible with UEFI booting mode. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode. This will enable this feature.

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS entry (sda2/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
The boot of your PC is in BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode. You may want to retry after changing it to UEFI mode.
```

To use the recommended repair option will not succeed: The current session is in BIOS - compatibility mode. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware and use this software from a live CD or live USB.

I haven't the slightest idea how to do this. Also sourceforge.net, which delivers such a live CD, does not work: The webpage at https://sourceforge.net/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Also other options of that program therefore do not work.

I reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04, but this problems remains.

Comment: You have UEFI based system and Ubuntu installed in UEFI boot mode. But also have installed grub in old BIOS boot mode which then will not work. Make sure system is set to boot in UEFI mode. And when booting live installer only boot in UEFI:xxx not xxx mode where xxx is name or label of your flash drive.  Message is from trying network boot which must be in list of options to try when default does not work. If you want Boot-Repair use Ubuntu live installer and ppa to add Boot-Repair to live installer. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair See second option. Only boot in UEFI mode.